# How to adjust renderer from default Phaser.Auto to Phaser.Canvas

Tags: phaser-framework

Where can I change the renderer in this code?

```
import { WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT } from './config'
import Game from './state/Game'

class App extends Phaser.Game {
    constructor () {
        super(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, Phaser.AUTO)
        this.state.add('Game', Game)
        this.state.start('Game')
    }
}

const SimpleGame = new App()
```

and game is

```
class Game extends Phaser.State {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.player = {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor, more specifically in the `super` call to `Phaser.Game`'s constructor:

```
class App extends Phaser.Game {
    constructor () {
        super(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, Phaser.CANVAS);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Reference: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Game.html